# Como chamar a janela modal com parâmetro no bootstrap?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber como eu posso chamar a abertura de uma janela modal no bootstrap passando um parâmetro. A ideia é abrir o item inserido da nota fiscal para editar a quantidade.

Comment: Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/605/ - Referencia: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10635652/1244639

Comment: É um modal externo (vai abrir de outro arquivo) ou o código já é estático na tela?

Answer (score 1):

Voce não consegue passar como parametro não. O que vc pode fazer é criar um input hidden dentro do modal para jogar os dados que necessita.